# WebMIDI on Chromium?

Tags: audio, web-browsers, chromium, midi

I'm doing some [WebMIDI](https://webaudio.github.io/web-midi-api/) programming for fun, and I'd like to get it running on a RPi. As I understand it, the WebMIDI API should be implemented on recent versions of Chromium, but could any of you verify that it is actually working? A simple test is to open the Inspector in Chromium on a RPI and entering 
`typeof(navigator.requestMIDIAccess)!=="undefined"`. If it returns `true`, then it should be working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Running

```
typeof(navigator.requestMIDIAccess)!=="undefined";
```

in the console returns **True**, on Version 47.0.2526.73 Ubuntu 15.04.